# Trying to iterate through data in JSON

Tags: json, python-3.x, for-loop

I have a REST API for all police reports coming in, and I'm trying to iterate through the result of the GET request.

```
import requests
import json
import time

query = "http://gismaps.wichita.gov/agsweb/rest/services/COWGIS/WPD_Public/MapServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=CATEGORY,ADDRESS,PBADDRESS,CASEADDRESS,CITY,STARTDATE,DOW,INCMONTH,MONTHHS,OFFENSE_CO,OFFENSE_DE,PLACE_DESC,CLASS_TYPE,Shape,INCREPORT,STARTDATET,STARTTIME&outSR=4326&f=json"
query_value = requests.get(query)
crime = query_value.json()

def search(num):
    for i in range(1, num):
        print(crime["features"][i]["attributes"]["CATEGORY"])


search(10)
```

This code returns this data:

`AGG_ASSAULT
DISORDERLY
VANDALISM
DISORDERLY
DRUGS
DRUGS
OTHERTRAF_VIO
OTHERTRAF_VIO
LARCENY`

But when I run this code:

```
import requests
import json
import time

query = "http://gismaps.wichita.gov/agsweb/rest/services/COWGIS/WPD_Public/MapServer/0/query?where=1%3D1&outFields=CATEGORY,ADDRESS,PBADDRESS,CASEADDRESS,CITY,STARTDATE,DOW,INCMONTH,MONTHHS,OFFENSE_CO,OFFENSE_DE,PLACE_DESC,CLASS_TYPE,Shape,INCREPORT,STARTDATET,STARTTIME&outSR=4326&f=json"
query_value = requests.get(query)
crime = query_value.json()

def search(num):
    amt = 0
    for i in range(1, num):
        #print(crime["features"][i]["attributes"]["CATEGORY"])
        value = crime["features"][i]["attributes"]["CATEGORY"]
        print(str(value))
        if str(value) == "DRUGS":
            amt + 1
    print(amt, "matches")


search(10)
```

It returns "0 matches", even though it clearly outputs that there are 2 reports that have a value of "DRUGS", and it's returning me 0. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Is `print(str(value))` printing all the same values?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to remove it from the code, it simply prints out the name of the crime

Comment: "name of the crime"? Add the output to your question by clicking the edit button. Also add `print(crime["features"][:num])` before the loop and add its output

Answer (score 0):

The line `amt + 1` doesn't do much. To increment the counter, use `amt += 1`.

Comment: Thanks! I'm kind of new to python and totally overlooked that.